# SED command to add or update IP address from variable to /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I am developing a deployment script "that I want to be able to run over again without double entries"

I am trying to add a sed command that will look for "address" field, if it doesn't exist, create it, if it does exist modify it to the correct IP Address.

This is what I have so far...

```
#!/bin/bash
ipaddress=192.168.1.1
sudo grep -q '^address' /etc/network/interfaces && sudo sed -i 's/^address.*/"address $ipaddress"/' /etc/network/interfaces || echo "address ${ipaddress}" >> /etc/network/interfaces
```

It will create the correct entry if no entry exists but **I have all kinds of problems if the entry exists or is correct.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Final Answer based on response from "1stSi Dave" Below

The final working script that creates the entry if it doesn't exist or alters any existing address entry is:

```
sudo grep -q '^address' /etc/network/interfaces && sudo sed -i -e 's/^address.*/address '$ipaddress'/' /etc/network/interfaces || echo "address ${ipaddress}" >> /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: what is the `/etc/network/interfaces` contents?

Comment: You should probably explain "I have all kinds of problems if the entry exists or is correct.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you need the '-e' command line option to your sed command:

```
sed -i -e 's/...'
```

Maybe that's a typo, because the rest of your command line indicates you want to append to the file, not edit in place.  Next, single quotes are hiding the variable expansion you're trying to achieve in the sed command script.  They are also preserving the double quotes in the output, which I don't think is what you want.  Try this:

```
sed -e 's/^address.*/address '$ipaddress'/' /etc/network/interfaces
```

Third, you may want to include the possibility of white space preceding the "address" token.  Finally, you probably **do** want to edit-in-place (with sed -i), because tacking on the edited line at the end of the file is probably not going to work.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed...I replaced your recommended command and appended the -i to it and have this:    'sudo grep -q '^address' /etc/network/interfaces && sudo sed -i -e 's/^address.*/address '$ipaddress'/' /etc/network/interfaces || echo "address ${ipaddress}" >> /etc/network/interfaces'  The command above will look for an entry with address, if it does not exist it will create one.  If address exists then it will append what is existing to match.  Thank you so much for your time.